# What’s wrong in the following reasoning that every idempotent matrix is the zero matrix or the identity matrix correct?

Tags: matrices, solution-verification

Suppose A is an nxn idempotent matrix.

Then this means that $AA=A$
$\iff AA-A= 0_{n\times n}$
$\iff A(A-I_{nxn})=0_{n \times n}$

$A=0_{n\times n}$ or $A=I_{n \times n}$

This would imply that any idempotent matrix is either the identity or the zero matrix...

Comment: Matrices in general do not behave like real numbers. For real numbers, if $xy=0$ then $x=0$ or $y=0$. This is not the case for matrices. So, you cannot make that jump. (in abstract terms, we say $\Bbb{R}$ is an integral domain, but for any $n\geq 2$, $M_{n\times n}(\Bbb{R})$ is not). As an explicit counterexample, look at the matrix $B=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$. Then, $B\cdot B=0$, but $B\neq 0$.

Comment: the last part is wrong - you can have nonzero matrices A and B such that AB =0

Answer (score 1):

Any matrix that is a diagonal matrix and the diagonal entries are zeroes and ones only, is idempotent. For example,
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}.$$
Convince yourself that indeed $AA=A$. Also observe that $A(A-I)=0$, but neither $A$ nor $A-I$ is zero.